# Objective C- Import error with singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I am quite new on Objective C so please be a bit slow with me.

I have constructed my Views like this: ViewController=>Root(View)=>Controls(View). Root is a Singleton so I can get the root element of my App any time.

When I add `#import "Root.h"` to `Controls.h` I get a parse issue.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Root.h"      // triggers the error

@interface Controls : UIView

@end
```

Here my Root.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Controls.h"
#import "Content.h"

@interface Root : UIView
{
    Controls *m_controls; // Parse error: Unknown type name "Controls"
}
+(Root*)getInstance;
@end
```

What causes that? How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use #import *.h only in *.m file, when you need use some class in *.h you could use @class.

So, you must change your class like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class Root 
@interface Controls : UIView
@end
```

and in *.m file:

> **#import "Root.h"**

Answer (score 1):

You have an import dependency loop.  Root.h imports Controls.h and vice versa.  One of them has to go first, and that one doesn't know about the declaration in the other.

In general, do as many of your imports in the implementation (.m) file as possible and use forward declarations in the .h like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Content.h"

@class Controls;

@interface Root : UIView
{
    Controls *m_controls;  //Prase error: Unknown type name "Controls"
}
+(Root*)getInstance;
@end
```

Incidentally, you can now put instance variables in the `@implementation` insead of the `@interface`

Comment: is there no way to avoid the loop? like #pragma once or #ifndef file_h ?

Comment: @asdf No.  At the end of the day, one of the two headers has to appear first in the compilation stream.